# CONCURRENT SELECT's SLOW .... LOCK IN SHARE MODE

Tags: mysql, select, locking

My Table has 25 Million rows total and 6 million rows satisfying below where clause.

Select 1:

```
select max(stamp) from Table where type = "string" LOCK IN SHARE MODE ;  6000+ seconds
```

Select 2:

```
select * from Table where type = "string" LOCK IN SHARE MODE ;  3000+ seconds
```

Select 3:

```
select * from Table where type = "string" LOCK IN SHARE MODE ;  2000+ seconds
```

If I try the SELECTS 2 and 3 without `LOCK IN SHARE MODE WITH LIMIT`, I am getting the data almost immediately.

All three queries have locked d table in shared mode. I don't understand why these are taking too much time when we use `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`.

```
Engine is Innodb,

Primary key is a composite key on multiple fields all are varchars


Create Table: CREATE TABLE `T1` (
`TYPE` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`FIELD2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`FIELD3` varchar(130) NOT NULL,
`FIELD4` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`FIELD5` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`FIELD6` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`FIELD7` varchar(110) NOT NULL,
.....
.....
.....
`STAMP` timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),

PRIMARY KEY (`TYPE`,`FEILD2`,`FEILD3`,`FEILD4`,`FEILD5`,`FEILD6`,`FEILD7`),
KEY `COM_KEY` (`FIELD9`,`FIELD9`,`STAMP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB?

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX(type, stamp)` should speed up "Select 1" significantly, even without `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`.

(Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for further discussion.)

**Edit**

Even though you have `type` and `stamp` in indexes, having these two fields in this order will be optimal for "Select 1":  `INDEX(type, stamp)`.  This is because the optimizer can drill into the BTree to the end of the "type='string'" values and find the MAX.  Instantly.  Only one rows is fetched.  And it is only fetched in the index.

With `PRIMARY KEY(type, other stuff)` it needs to scan 6M rows to find the answer.  `COM_KEY` is of no help (for this SELECT).

After this query is sped up, the other queries may be less of a problem.

Comment: Rick, There is a primary key on (`type`) but not on (type, stamp). There is no useful key on (`stamp`).

Comment: Before reacting to that, I need to know the Engine, size of rows, indexes, etc.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If you have 6M rows with type='string', then it is impossible for the `PRIMARY KEY` to be '(type)'.  A PK is UNIQUE.

Comment: (Updated my Answer)

Comment: Rick, Thanks for your time. My SELECT 1 took 3.5 Hours to completed. My main question is not how to speed this up, instead why this SELECT 1 is that much slow ?

Comment: I thought the second paragraph of my Edit answered "why".  You can use `EXPLAIN SELECT ... ` to see that it is probably using the `PRIMARY KEY` for the query.  If you have a new enough version of MySQL, do `ALTER TABLE T1 ADD INDEX(type, stamp) ALGORITHM=INPLACE;` to add the index with minimal impact.

Comment: Oh, more questions:  Are any of these SELECTs inside transactions?  What is the value of autocommit when running them?

Comment: None of them is inside a transaction. and auto commit is ON.

 
What difference it brings in if all of them are inside different transactions ? 

 
Current isolation level is READ-COMMITTED